# query selector javascript not excuted in python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

```
driver.excute_script('document.querySelector("button[type=\"submit\"]").click();')
```

And also try this:

```
driver.excute_script('document.querySelector("button[type=\"submit\"]").click()');
```

It shows the error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):   File "C:\Users\gggg\Desktop\JJ.py", line 6
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\gggg\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options) DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\gggg\Desktop\JJ.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('button[type=\'submit\']').click();");   File "C:\Users\gggg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 634, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {   File "C:\Users\gggg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\gggg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list   (Session info: headless chrome=84.0.4147.135)
```

Comment: Small typo driver.execute_script on the execute. Also python doesn't use semicolons. The inside will need a semicolon though.

Comment: What does the button html look like?

Answer (score 1):

When you execute this:

```py
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("button[type=\"submit\"]").click();')
```

On JS side this will look like

```js
document.querySelector("button[type="submit"]").click();
```

and querySelector attempts to evaluate `"button[type="` and find the closing `)` but finds `submit` instead. Hence the exception: `javascript error: missing ) after argument list` .

To solve the problem use `'` and `"` both in your js expression and enclose your python string in triple quotes:

```py
driver.execute_script('''document.querySelector("button[type='submit']").click();''')
```

Or you could use

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
```

and not to worry about triple quotes.

Or if you want to use the js click() instead of selenium's click for some reason:

```py
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", elem)
```